# Select after login via Batch (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, ssms

I am trying to select data from table and save them info .csv file via .bat file. 
My batch runs Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and log me into database, but I am not able to execute sql scripts.
Here is what I have:

```
    @echo off
    cls
    :begin
    set /p SName=Server Name :
    set /p DbName=Database Name :
    set /p UName=User Name :
    set /p DbPWD=Password :
    pause
    echo Running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, please wait
    call ssms -S %SName% -d %DbName% -U %UName% -P %DbPWD% "select * from MYTABLE" -s "," -o " Export.csv"        
    echo Done
    pause
    :end
```

It does not work after line: `ssms -S %SName% -d %DbName% -U %UName% -P %DbPWD%`

UPDATE:
[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxCH.png)

Thank you

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Smart quotes (“ ”) tend to not be appreciated by any tools other than Microsoft Word. Use regular quotes (") and don't break lines where this is not supported. More to the point, wouldn't you rather use `sqlcmd` to run queries, rather than Management Studio?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No, I don't. It just post the echo about SSMS and that is all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I changed quotes and it did not change anything. And unfortunately I can't use sqlcmd in this case. But thank you for your advice.

Comment: Nikola, in your comment to @JeroenMostert, you said you'd changed the quotes, did you fix the unsupported line break too? Also please understand that readers shouldn't generally have to read through all comments in order to provide help; it is advised that you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51498505/edit), to reflect updates you make.

Comment: Try to insert a `call` command this way: `call ssms -S %SName% -d %DbName% -U %UName% -P %DbPWD% "select * from MYTABLE" -s "," -o "Export.csv"`

Comment: @NikolaHažmuková Please elaborate on your problem using sqlcmd.  it is custom made for just this kind of thing.  Also, BCP is a viable alternative here, I think

Comment: @NikolaHažmuková, `"select * from MYTABLE" -s "," -o " Export.csv"` isn't an independent internal or external command. Remember what was suggested about unsupported line breaks!

Comment: @Compo Thank you very much, I am not very familiar witch batch files so my biggest problem is that I have no idea how to "go" from login to script in the right way.

Comment: Nicola, please see the advice provided in the comment by @Aacini?

Comment: @NikolaHažmuková SSMS does not accept an in-line script from the command line, as you are trying to do.  Please use SQLCMD for this work.  that's why you got the error message.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Nikola you could just write sqlcmd -S <your server instance> -i <path to your .sql file> -o <path to your output file>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS does not accept an in-line script from the command line, as you are trying to do. Please use SQLCMD for this work. that's why you got the error message.

See [SSMS Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/ssms-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?view=sql-server-2014)

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i <MyScript.sql> -o <MyOutput.rpt>
```